# How can I exclude blocks in XML files using CPD?

Tags: android, xml, pmd, cpd

In a large project multiple android resources are used. It now happens that there are resources copied. I want to detect these copies using [CPD](https://pmd.github.io/). Currently I'm using the following command:

```
./run.sh cpd --language xml --minimum-tokens 20 --files $RES_FOLDER
```

Unfortunately most XML files contains at least a declaration line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

followed by some header:

```
<!--
  -- Copyright 2017, all rights reserved.
  -->
```

There is an option `--skip-blocks-pattern` but it seems to be ignored.

Anybody any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear this can't be done at the moment.

The `--skip-blocks-pattern` is a cpp only flag, used to ignore `#if 0 ... #endif` blocks.

There are plans to provide the ignore support through comments on all / most supported languages in the near future. We recently added such support experimentally on Java and so far had good results, so we may soon promote it across the board.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.